# What is the difference between "Close alert" and "Set Resolution State -> Closed" in SCOM?

Tags: scom

What is the difference between "Close alert" and "Set Resolution State -> Closed" in SCOM?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. "Close Alert" updates the resolution state of the alert to 255 - so does "Set Resolution State -> Closed"